# How to toggle (hide/show) a table onClick of <a> tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, toggle

I want to show and hide (toggle) the `<table>` `onClick` event of the `<a>`.
this is my `<a>` tag

```
<a id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable(true);" href="#">Login</a>
```

Here is my Javascript function `toggleTable(hide)`:

```
   <script>
    function toggleTable(hide)
    {
    if (hide) {
       document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="table";
       document.getElementById("loginLink").onclick = toggleTable(false);
   
    } else {
       document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="none";
       document.getElementById("loginLink").onclick = toggleTable(true);
    }
   }
   </script>
```

and here is my `<table>` tag:

```
<table id="loginTable" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
```

The first time when I click the `<a> link` it shows my table, but not hiding back when I click it next time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are always sending 'true'. Just hide the table if it is visible and show if it is hidden

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to alter the behaviour of `onclick` inside the same function call. Try it like this:

### Anchor tag

```
<a id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable();" href="#">Login</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
function toggleTable() {
    var lTable = document.getElementById("loginTable");
    lTable.style.display = (lTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
```

Comment: can u explain it a little please?

Comment: @QadirHussain [Ternary operator(`?...:`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) or the [`onclick`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/handling-events-with-javascript/)?

Comment: Is't possible to use Anchor without using # in href or what control(or asp control) to use inplace of <a ...>.?

Comment: How would you make it so the table is hidden by default?

Comment: @Moms set `display="none"` as a css attribute.

Answer (score 7):

Simple using jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginLink').click(function() {
    $('#loginTable').toggle('slow');
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: where should i paste it. sorry newbie for jquery.

Comment: add this line in <head> tag <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
and then paste this script anywhere in your html part.

Comment: @Qadir Hussain i think its simple way.

Comment: yes upvote for this. but i need the code in java script. hjpotter92 answer is nice also. Many thanks to you also

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your function as:

```
function toggleTable()
{
   if (document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display == "table" ) {
       document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="none";

   } else {
      document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="table";

}
```

currently it is checking based on the `boolean` parameter, you don't have to pass the parameter with your function.

You need to modify your anchor tag as:

```
<a id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable();" href="#">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

inside your function `toggleTable` when you do this line

```
document.getElementById("loginLink").onclick = toggleTable(....
```

you are actually calling the function again. so `toggleTable` gets called again, and again and again, you're falling in an infinite recursive call.

make it simple.

```
function toggleTable()
{
     var elem=document.getElementById("loginTable");
     var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
     if (hide) {
         elem.style.display="table";
    } 
    else {
       elem.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfxpu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor tag should be:

```
  <a id="loginLink" onclick="showHideTable();" href="#">Login</a>
```

And You javascript function :

```
function showHideTable()
{
   if (document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display == "none" ) {
       document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="";

   } else {
      document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="none";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always passing in true to the toggleMethod, so it will always "show" the table.
I would create a global variable that you can flip inside the toggle method instead.

Alternatively you can check the visibility state of the table instead of an explicit variable

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
  function toggleTable()
    {

    var status = document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display;

    if (status == 'block') {
      document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("loginTable").style.display="block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` property makes the element visible or invisible.

```
function showTable(){
    document.getElementById('table').style.visibility = "visible";
}
function hideTable(){
    document.getElementById('table').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```